# How re-process an element by a second (non-named) template?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have separated certain statements to be applied on a specific element in a separate template.
The element is processed in one template, which contains a statement `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.
**Is there a way to have an element just processed in the first template, to be re-processed in the second (non-named) template?**
Of course I know that I could use a named template and call that from the first template, but I am just wondering whether it could be done like this.
To give you something to work with, here's a **heavily simplified** model of the stuff I am working on.
I have an html input file containing a table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
            <td></td>
            <td/>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I wish to have a `block` element inside each `td` element that encloses the `td` string content if there is one, or is empty when the `td` element itself is empty. I tried the following (note again that I do not wish to do major changes in the first template!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="test"><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td/text()">
        <block><xsl:value-of select="."/></block>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Where the added attribute is just a modelled example of the stuff that is being done in the first template.

which gives as output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table test="table">
    <tbody test="tbody">
        <tr test="tr">
            <td test="td">
                <block>content</block>
            </td>
            <td test="td"/>
            <td test="td"/>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and I wish to get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table test="table">
    <tbody test="tbody">
        <tr test="tr">
            <td test="td">
                <block>content</block>
            </td>
            <td test="td">
                <block/>
            </td>
            <td test="td">
                <block/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It is clear why it did not work: there is no text node in the empty `td` elements, so these are not matched by the second template's Xpath expression.
So I started thinking about ways to re-process the `td` elements itself by a second template. Of course, I can not use `match="td[some condition]"` because then the first template will not be applied.
And I can also not use `match= "self::td"` because the `self` axis is not allowed in template match attributes (except in conditions of course), or rather, it needs a current node which you don't have yet when starting to match.
So is there a suitable Xpath expression available for the second template that will give me what I want?
Or is there another simple way to trigger another (non-named) template for an element just processed in one template?
**Note: I am not looking for simple updates on the second template, that add the attribute there. I wish the first template to add the attribute, and the second to add the block elements.**

Comment: I deleted my original answer. Have you tried creating a moded match="td" template? You could then do something like `<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::td" mode="foo"/>`.

Comment: Yes tried that but did not succeed - but then I could have made a mistake so I will retry.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I added a new answer. +1 for a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding another "moded" template. You should be able to use `xsl:apply-templates` with the mode.

Example xsl:template:

```
<xsl:template match="td" mode="test">
  <bar>test</bar>
</xsl:template>
```

Example xsl:apply-templates:

```
<xsl:template match="td">
  <foo><xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::td" mode="test"/></foo>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes I was able to use something similar - silly I tried it earlier but made a mistake and thought that using mode-attribute would not help. Thanks for helping me back on track!

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`xsl:next-match`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/PR-xslt20-20061121/#element-next-match) in XSLT 2.0 or [`xsl:apply-imports`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-apply-imports) in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Will `xsl:apply-imports` be able to do something that a template in the original xslt cannot do?

Comment: @Maestro13 it isn't necessarily that it can do something the original can't, just a different way of doing things. Rather than having to use a mode, you can have simple logic in different stylesheets and decide when to apply it.  Imported templates have a lower precedence than the templates from the importing stylesheet. `<xsl:apply-imports>` allows you to tell the processor to use the templates from the imported stylesheet while inside of a template from the top level importing stylesheet.

Comment: @MichaelKay Michael your answer was OK - just a little too brief for me to realize its deeper meaning - Mads luckily provided the rest of the story so now I see that this is indeed a viable alternative to using modes.

Comment: Sorry about the terseness. When I'm too busy to give a full tutorial, I reckon it's still helpful to point people in the right direction: there's plenty of information out there once you've got a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

**An XSLT 1.0 solution that uses [`<xsl:apply-imports>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-apply-imports)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import href="block.xsl" />

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="test"><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="self::td">
                <xsl:apply-imports/>
            </xsl:if>  
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The imported stylesheet **block.xsl**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="td">
        <block><xsl:value-of select="."/></block>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**An XSLT 2.0 solution that uses [`<xsl:next-match>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/PR-xslt20-20061121/#element-next-match):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="test"><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="self::td">
                <!--apply the next template that would match this td element -->
                <xsl:next-match/>
            </xsl:if>  
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--calculated priority of "td" would be higher than "*",
        so explicitly setting a lower priority -->
    <xsl:template match="td" priority="-1">
        <block><xsl:value-of select="."/></block>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: A good alternative indeed - both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 solutions are very usable. Especially the 2.0 one is intuitively pleasing as it does exactly what is required: re-process an element with a lower-priority template.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I add the solution I arrived at by DevNull's answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="test"><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="td" select="self::td"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td" mode="td">
        <block><xsl:value-of select="."/></block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td/text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which results in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table test="table">
    <tbody test="tbody">
        <tr test="tr">
            <td test="td">
                <block>content</block>
            </td>
            <td test="td">
                <block></block>
            </td>
            <td test="td">
                <block></block>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note the added template to prevent processing td text nodes a second time by default templates.